# call asp.net webservice on localhost

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, localhost, asmx

I have been given a task where I have to write some code for an ASP.NET website that also uses  a webservice.

The webservice works fine on the webserver, but when i run in debug mode in Visual Studio, I get an access not allowed when calling one of the methods (ip 127.0.0.1).

I need to run in debug mode to look at what the code does...

What to do from here ?

1. Do I need to do some changes in the host file.
2. Do I need to install IIS on my PC instead of using the VS local webserver (cassini)

Comment: When I need to do this, I run two instances of visual studio.  Once running the webservice (in cassini) and one running my asp.net page.  When you run the webservice in cassini, you should have a path similar to http://localhost:9090 which you can point your asp.net application toward.  I think in the web.config it contains the uri to the web service.

Comment: I find I need to run IIS and VS as administrator to debug the service.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the 'access not allowed' error? What  HTTP error code?

Comment: Http error 401 - the problem is that I need to give the guys who are running the webservice (not coded by me) an IP to allow the calls and 127.0.0.1 won't work, because they need an individual IP. Is it possible to go in debug mode with a specific IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassini web server does not allow remote connections. You could use Fiddler to forward traffic on localhost to another port on the same machine for some given requests.

By far the easiest solution is to install IIS on your local machine and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Cassini is fine for development and getting something running up very quickl.

But *never* us it to test things that will go into production on a "real" IIS.

Yes, Microsoft says its completely the same, but running on your localmachine also IIS gives you *exactly* the same environment as you will have on any live hosting environment.

Sure, its a little bit more work, but developing this way reduces errors and artefacts which may steal you some time.